# Docker ECS Plugin AWS Context not setting docker ecs setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am following below docker documentation link in order to directly deploy my docker project on AWS ECS without changing anything

https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/ecs-integration/

I have successfully configured docker ecs plugin on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04). `docker ecs version` returns

**Docker ECS plugin v1.0.0-beta.2 (6629d8e)**

Tried to configure aws context as written in the documentation using the command `docker ecs setup` which opened an interactive mode allowing me to add credentials for aws account. It created a profile in **~/.aws/credentials**

When I run `docker context ls` I can not see aws context only "default" is shown

[image: context]

So when I run `docker ecs compose up` it says **can't use "default" with ECS command because it is not an AWS context** obviously because aws context is not setting.

It is expected that when I run `docker compose up` in the directory with `docker-compose.yml` file in  it it should create containers on ECS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was 'this tool requires the "new ARN resource ID format"'. This was reported as an issue on the original repo

```
https://github.com/docker/ecs-plugin/issues
```

Please see

```
https://github.com/docker/ecs-plugin/issues/175
```

to resolve the issue. Basically you need to set ARN formats to new from your ECS Console in AWS by gong to **ECS -> Account Setting**

[image]